# How to write this sql query efficiently in this case

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

Here I have a query like below and am looping the child id and passing it to this query and getting the appropriate result. Here I have 33 child ids so the result for this query contains 33 rows

```
DECLARE @DATETIMENOW DATETIME  
SET @DATETIMENOW = GETDATE()-7 

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM  BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP ON CHEP.EVENTID = CHE.EVENTID  
                      WHERE (CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT' OR (CHE.TYPE = 'BREAK' AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS' AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'))  
                      AND CHE.CHILDID = @CHILDID AND CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW-7)-1), @DATETIMENOW-7) AND  
                      DATEADD(DD, 7-(DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW-7)), @DATETIMENOW-7) AS PREVIOUSWEEKACCIDENTS
```

here instead of looping the childid I have tried using join in this query but am getting the result in a single row. what I am doing wrong in this

```
DECLARE @DATETIMENOW DATETIME  
SET @DATETIMENOW = GETDATE()-7 
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM  BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP 
                      ON CHEP.EVENTID = CHE.EVENTID 
                      JOIN  BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO
                      ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID
                      WHERE (CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT' OR (CHE.TYPE = 'BREAK' AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS' AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'))  
                      AND CHE.ADDDATE 
                      BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW-7)-1), @DATETIMENOW-7) AND  
                      DATEADD(DD, 7-(DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW-7)), @DATETIMENOW-7)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT  CHINFO.CHILDID
      , COUNT(1)
FROM    BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE
        JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP ON CHEP.EVENTID = CHE.EVENTID
        JOIN BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID
WHERE   ( CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT'
          OR ( CHE.TYPE = 'BREAK'
               AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS'
               AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'
             )
        )
        AND CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,
                                        -( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 7) - 1 ),
                                        @DATETIMENOW - 7)
                        AND     DATEADD(DD,
                                        7 - ( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 7) ),
                                        @DATETIMENOW - 7)
GROUP BY CHINFO.CHILDID
```

Comment: but null values are not displayed..i have tried left outer join but still am not getting the null values in result

Comment: Where will change a left join to a join

Answer (score 1):

A value in the where will invalidate an outer join

```
SELECT CHE.CHILDID
     , COUNT(1)
  FROM BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE
  LEFT JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP 
    ON CHEP.EVENTID = CHE.EVENTID
   AND ( CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT'
          OR ( CHE.TYPE = 'BREAK'
               AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS'
               AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'
             )
       )
   AND CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,
                                        -( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 7) - 1 ),
                                        @DATETIMENOW - 7)
                       AND DATEADD(DD,
                                        7 - ( DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW - 7) ),
                                        @DATETIMENOW - 7)    
GROUP BY CHE.CHILDID
```

Comment: +1 to Suart as I used his TSQL.  The question was in the comment for and hour so I went ahead and answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
          DECLARE @DATETIMENOW DATETIME  
          SET @DATETIMENOW = GETDATE()

              SELECT  B.WEEK FROM BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CI LEFT OUTER JOIN 

              (SELECT Distinct CHINFO.CHILDID,COUNT(*)  as week FROM  BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO               
               JOIN  BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE 
                            ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID                                                       
               JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP 
                            ON  CHE.EVENTID = CHEP.EVENTID                         
              WHERE 
                          (CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT' OR (CHE.TYPE = 'POTTYBREAK' AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS' 
                          AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'))  
                            AND 
                            CHE.ADDDATE 
                            BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW-14)-1), @DATETIMENOW-14) AND  
                            DATEADD(DD, 7-(DATEPART(DW, @DATETIMENOW-14)), @DATETIMENOW-14)      group by CHINFO.CHILDID) b
                            on CI.ChildID = b.ChildID
```